# Show/hide form fields depending on radio button click

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a radio button that when checked, I would like the below two fields shown/hidden. How would this be achievable via JS?

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch mt-3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtk1" name="rtk[checked][]" value="1">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtk1">The categories of personal information <?= $config->get_company(); ?> has collected about you.</label>
</div>
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
        <i>Please provide the following information to be used for verification purposes:</i>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <label for="rtk1Field1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Field 1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rtk1Field1" name="rtk[1][field1]" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Field 1 is required.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <label for="rtk1Field2" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Field 2</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rtk1Field2" name="rtk[1][field2]" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Field 2 is required.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean you have a checkbox, not a radio?

Comment: Also, what have you attempted so far, if anything?  Questions are expected have made an attempt already.  Otherwise they can be viewed as coding requests, which are off topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/prceax3v/3/

HTML

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch mt-3">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rtk1" name="rtk[checked][]" value="1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="rtk1">The categories of personal information <?= $config->get_company(); ?> has collected about you.</label>
</div>
<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-11">
    <i>Please provide the following information to be used for verification purposes:</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='form-wrapper'>


  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <label for="rtk1Field1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Field 1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rtk1Field1" name="rtk[1][field1]" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Field 1 is required.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <label for="rtk1Field2" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Field 2</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rtk1Field2" name="rtk[1][field2]" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Field 2 is required.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
const formWrapper = document.getElementById('form-wrapper');

document.getElementById('rtk1').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    formWrapper.style.display = 'none'
  } else {
    formWrapper.style.display = ''
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @ScottMarcus, but .. must be blind not seeing code inside my request.

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents I see HTML, but no JavaScript attempt.

Answer (score 0):

First, what you've provided is a checkbox, not a radio button. If you want to use a checkbox, you can accomplish what you're asking with the following code:

```
document.querySelector('input#rtk1').addEventListener( 'change', function() {
if(this.checked) {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').forEach(function(el) {
      el.style.display = 'none';
    });
} else {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.display = 'block';
  });
}
});
```

If you want to hide the labels next to each text field as well, I would suggest adding a unique class to each row container such as, `text-input-container`, then putting that class name inside the querySelectorAll calls instead of `input[type="text"]`